# Tabata calorie burn with 4 minute excersie

Tags: cardio, hiit, tabata

I have started doing cardio from one Youtube channel which is showing that in 84 min I can burn around 1000 calories (but 1000 is not my goal). I do gym also so I want to burn till 400-500 calories.
While searching on youtube I found these tutorials for tabata

[Burn fat in 4 min](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFt3iRT5ueg)

[4 min jump around tabata](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLfb54HUtuA)

by searching it on google I found that it burn around 15 calorie per minute (assuming that it has been performed with 100% effort)

but some of the website users claim that they have burned around 200 calories, which is astonishing because he didn't mention after burn.

So my questions are,

1. As there are many 4 minutes video available online for Tabata. Does all pattern burn same amount of calorie per minute? Do I have to worry about which exercise pattern I choose?
2. Assuming that Tabata burns 15 calorie per minute so total would be 15*4 = 60 calorie. 
   Do I have to repeat the set or after burn can help me reducing more calorie?

*I know this may be hard to calculate but I would appreciate if you can guide me with the approximate calorie reduce (after burn) when a person do only 4 min Tabata routine*

Comment: Your calorie burn will be determined by the *intensity of the exercises.* So, a simple exercise such as sprinting should burn more than walking *because the intendity will vary*. As for the specific calorie calculation, I highly doubt that you can obtain the specific numbers to look for; *a range of numbers* might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*I have done some research on internet on my question and I would try to answer my own question, but I will not accept this as an official answers until this gets an appropriate amount of up votes.*

- Tabata work out burns around 12 calorie/min to 16 calorie/min.
- A common formula involves a 2:1 ratio of work to recovery periods, for example, 30–40 seconds of hard sprinting alternated with 15–20 seconds of jogging or walking. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_interval_training))
- Few sample tabata workout routine are mention below, it really doesn't effect too much on what type of exercise you choose it is about how much effort you put into it.

[image]

- based on the intensity of the workout, calorie burning effect appears more at "after burn", this is the actually similar to any HIIT workout training.
  an additional 150 calories are being burned up to 12 hours after you do 4 min Tabata.

so, mathematically (assuming an average scenario)

```
4 *15 = 60 (4 min workout)
     + 150 
------------
       210 calories
```

[image]

The style of workout can take between 4-20 minutes. It is noteworthy that Tabata should not be perform for long period of time (i.e. > 20 minutes).

**I would still be looking for someone who can post the real calorie measurement, measured via equipment like HRM**

**[Not related to question]**

*Just because I read about it and I feel responsible to post it in my answer which might be useful for a beginner and will help them to avoid unnecessary injury and loss*

*Whatever the case, you should get clearance from a doctor prior to starting full-blown Tabata training, or any form of HIIT for that matter, if any of the following apply to you:*

- *You’re over 40 years of age*
- *You’re a smoker*
- *You have high blood pressure*
- *You or someone in your family has a history of any type of
  cardiovascular disease*
- *You have asthma*
- *You have a history of any type of breathing problems*

Comment: The additional 150 calories over 12 hours is a bit of an overestimation. IIRC when I looked at it, it was in the order of 25-50 calories over 24ish hours.